# Reinstall/Upgrade all python user-site's packages and not Ubuntu global ones

Tags: command-line, package-management, permissions, python, pip

When I first installed Ubuntu (16.04 LTS), I didn't realize that (in general) it isn't a good idea to install python packages through `pip` using `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install mypackage
```

But, whenever I wanted to install a package without `sudo` I would get permission denied.

Now, I realize I should have just installed most/all of these packages using the `--user` flag:

```
pip install --user mypackage
```

which will prevent any package from executing unwanted code on my computer with root privileges. (I also now have a better environment setup using virtualenv and similar).

However I still have a lot of packages installed with `pip` which I would like to reinstall as a user instead of root. But, as I understand, Ubuntu has some python packages it has installed by default (through `apt-get`, but these are still listed and can be removed by `pip`). So my question is: how can I remove (and reinstall) all of the packages I have installed without messing up the ones Ubuntu uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Correct way

Create a list of all python packages:

```
pip list --format=legacy | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/.*/\L&/' | sort  > /tmp/list.pip
```

then create a list of all these packages which were installed by `apt`:

```
cat /tmp/list.pip | sed 's/.*/\L&/' | 
xargs -Ipkg dpkg -l python-pkg python3-pkg pkg |& grep ^ii |
 awk '{print $2}' | sed -r s/^python3?-// | sort | uniq > /tmp/list.apt
```

Now we got to list of python packages, `/tmp/list.pip` which `pip` is able to remove, and `/tmp/list.apt` which are packages installed by `apt`, check them manually and remove the ones that are not in `/tmp/apt.list`.

---

**Because of different naming convention between apt and pip, the solution bellow is not working correctly**. I'll fix it latter...

Finally get a list of all packages that been installed only by `pip` and not `apt` (packages exists in file `/tmp/list.pip` but not `/tmp/list.apt`):

```
comm /tmp/list.apt /tmp/list.pip -3 > /tmp/list_toRemove
```

Then use `/tmp/list_toRemove` content to remove or upgrade your `pip` packages.

For example to remove them all you can run:

```
pip uninstall $(cat /tmp/list_toRemove)
```

and to reinstall them:

```
pip install $(cat /tmp/list_toRemove) --user
```

---

#### Wrong way

Using commands like:

```
pip list --user
pip list --local
pip freeze --user
pip freeze --local
```

also includes packages installed by `apt` from specific paths, so do not use these commands.

Comment: Your second command (`dpkg -l $(cat /tmp/list.pip)`...) doesn't seem to capture all packages installed through `apt`. For instance: `apt search jinja | grep installed` tells me I have python-Jinja2 installed through `apt`, yet this does not come up in `/tmp/list.apt`.

Comment: The second command only includes packages which are visible through `pip`, so there is no need to find all packages installed by `apt`, we get a list of all packages which can be controlled through `pip` then we exclude the ones which `apt` knows about.

Comment: `pip list` shows `Jinja2` as an installed package. Is the `Jinja2` that `pip` knows about not the same package as the `python-jinja2` that `apt` knows about?

Comment: @DanielHathcock Okay, I checked it again... because of different naming convention between `apt` and `pip` these things might happen, I updated the answer to fix the issue, however you should check the lists manually, this is the closest thing that I could get... the other thing is you might have 2 version of a package, one installed by apt the other by pip... that's really hard to detect too.

Comment: I did catch several that had strange names (i.e. `pyxdg` through `pip`, but `python-xdg` through `apt`). Other than that this worked well. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful to you :)